# String enum as map key does not work with ReturnType

Tags: typescript

I am trying to assign type for `functions`. The following code works.

```
enum Enum {
  Foo = "foo"
}

const functions = {
  [Enum.Foo]: () => "Hello World!"
};

type FunctionMap = { [key: string]: (...args: any[]) => any };
type FunctionUnion<T extends FunctionMap> = ReturnType<T[keyof T]>;

type functions = FunctionUnion<typeof functions>;
```

However, if I change the key type of `FunctionMap`,

```
type FunctionMap = { [key in Enum]: (...args: any[]) => any };
```

It throws

> Type 'T[keyof T]' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any[]) => any'.
>     Type 'FunctionMap[keyof T]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any[]) => any'.ts(2344)

Why does it throw errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an error with enums because the index signature `[key: string]` means that any property that can ever exist on `FunctionMap` has to be of type `(...args: any[]) => any`. The mapped type over `Enum` on the other hand means just that properties that are present in the enum will have to be functions, the type makes no guarantees abou other properties. So this is valid :

```
enum Enum {
  Foo = "foo"
}

const functions = {
  [Enum.Foo]: () => "Hello World!",
  otherProp: "string"
};

type FunctionMap = { [key in Enum]: (...args: any[]) => any };
type FunctionUnion<T extends FunctionMap> = ReturnType<T[keyof T]>;
type functions = FunctionUnion<typeof functions>; //ok  here otherProp is not a problem
```

One option is to filter out non function types with a conditional type:

```
enum Enum {
  Foo = "foo"
}

const functions = {
  [Enum.Foo]: () => "Hello World!",
  otherProp: "string"
};

type FunctionMap = { [key in Enum]: (...args: any[]) => any };
type FunctionUnion<T extends FunctionMap> = { 
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? ReturnType<T[P]> : never;
}[keyof T]
type functions = FunctionUnion<typeof functions>;
```

Comment: Ok, for who does not understand. `[key in Enum]` only grantee key thats are `Enum` are functions. Because `FunctionUnion` is using `T extends FunctionMap` which means, `T` can have keys other that `Enum` which may not be a function.